# Classic Asp - Server.CreateObject failed

Tags: asp-classic

We have an old application that still works on classic Asp. There is a problem witch the contact form that whenever we try to run it, it gives the below error :

> Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'
>
> Server.CreateObject Failed
>
> /inc/Functions.asp, line 1193

and the line 1193 is :

```
set ObjSendMail = Server.CreateObject("something")
```

I tried unregistering and registering mswcrun.dll and it didn't work and I have limited knowledge about classic Asp. What could we be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you replaced the *'something'* or is that what was written in there? Check to see if you have CDOSYS.DLL registered (you may want to check for CDONTS.DLL if this is a very old application). I also [found this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/188289) which could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If it literally says:

Server.CreateObject("something")

I'm quite sure that is sample code, while it still is possible, I don't think anyone would call their object "something".

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and after much research i found the solution ,check if its working for you. 
Remote scripting causes tons of errors with different IE versions. If your are passing control from one page to another and creating a new object from there you will get this kind of unable to create object error.

Example:

```
page x.asp--

function1call() 
function2call() 

further in page x.asp--

function1call(){
   var rs_obj = RSGetASPObject("some-object");
   ----some other things---
   frmPost.action = "someplace.asp"; 
   frmPost.submit();
}  

function2call(){
   var rs_obj = RSGetASPObject("some-object1"); //you wont be able to create 
                                                //this object
   ----some other things---
}
```

It seems like the remoteScripting object is not getting initiated . As function1call() calls frmPost.submit().

If you combine these 2 functions it will start to work. I.E

page x.asp--

```
function1call(){
   var rs_obj = RSGetASPObject("some-object");
   var rs_obj = RSGetASPObject("some-object1"); 
   ----some other things---
   frmPost.action = "someplace.asp"; 
   frmPost.submit();

}
```